# Tag badges are shown as awarded before they are actually awarded

Tags: discussion, bug, tag-badges, badge-progress

I have observed that the profile tag badge tracker is out of sync with actual awarding of badges.  As an experienced user I assume this is simply a caching issue but I think it is unnecessarily confusing.  I think the badge tracker should show "pending" or something like that until the badge is actually awarded.

For example I recently completed the requirement for a Silver "front-end" tag badge on Mathematica:

[image]

However the actual badge list does not include it yet:

[image]